# Regex: Exclude characters from right in the string until numeric is found

Tags: regex

I have a string in the following format:

```
ABC12233434343DEF
```

How can I extract only:

```
ABC12233434343
```

I want to leave out the ending set of characters of whatever length they might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways this is one:

```
.*?\d+
```

It will match `anything` at the beginning that is followed by numbers.

It may be also posible to limit the characters it can match initially, like if you was capital letters from A-Z, for example:

```
[A-Z]+\d+
```

[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FqDUW9/1)

Comment: If I am not wrong, `?` is used to make it non-greedy?

Comment: yes takes the greedy behavior in the expression and reduce the steps. The 2nd expression is more efficient but it depends on the limitations you may add